# What is the the most straightforward way of using all Html Verbs in a Restful ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-verbs

Until now I have always just used `post` and `get` on my controller actions.

I'd like to use all of the major verbs in my app in order to [a] adhere to standards for rest, and [b] well, not use get and post exclusively.

The additional verbs I'd like to use are

- Put
- Delete
- Patch

What is the most straightforward way of achieving this? I know that all of the required verbs (other than `patch`) are available for `[AcceptVerbs(...)]`, but I'm not fully sure how to implement them.

Comment: it this for an API, or a website that primarily serves HTML (and the odd JSON for ajax requests)?

Comment: Well, each Action is going to decide what kind of content to serve. Basically it's going to serve as both a website AND and api depending on the content request... ie: `if(request.Headers("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH") == "xmlhttprequest"){return JSON;}else{return View();}`

Comment: hmmm....a website and an API in one? not sure about that. I would seperate them, for quite a few reasons. Allowing the API to stay "live" whilst you update your main website with minuscule changes (UI, javascript, etc) for one. JS, CSS, ViewModels, etc - the API doesn't use or care about this, so why should a change to one of these components affect it's online status? Matter of opinion i guess.

Comment: I can update the front end while keeping the server side live no problem. I just don't want to have to write identical actions for each uri, seems like a lot of redundant code.

Comment: so if you want to for example add a new view model as a result of a change in one of the *Website* pages, how would you update the *Website* without stopping the *API*? Unless you deploy them as seperate websites in IIS, you can't

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the MVC4 beta that was just released, and this includes the new WebAPI that will automatically do restful requests.  You can even install only the WebAPI and use it under MVC3.  It includes a go-live license as well.

However, if you're stuck with non-beta then you have to do a little more work.  Here's a good rundown.

http://iwantmymvc.com/rest-service-mvc3

Answer (score 1):

You can override the post method in the view as follows,

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController",FormMethod.Post))
{

   %>
   <%:Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Put) %>
   <%
} %>
```

Then in the Controller, you can have `[HttpPut]`

Comment: As I think about it, I can also accept two verbs on the controller `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpDelete]` for example.